# Equivalent of ServletContextListener in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, servletcontextlistener

In Java, we can implement and configure an interface that listens when the application is being deployed and undeployed through [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). For example, I can execute some tasks to load data in global cache at deploy time and execute temporary files removal tasks when the application is undeployed (these are just examples, doesn't mean I will do some of them in my app).

Is there an equivalent class/interface in asp.net applications? Or how can I achieve this behavior?

I would want to perform some tasks when the web application is being undeployed (stopped) rather than when it is deployed (started).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ServletContextListener notifies when a servlet is added to or removed from a context. ASP.NET applications are not servlets, and are not loaded into a context, so there's no complete equivalent.

There are Application* events, however. Create an ASP.NET web application and look in Global.asax.cs:

- [`ServletContext#contextInitialized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) equivalent is `Application_Start` method.
- [`ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) equivalent is `Application_End` method.

More info:

- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0. Using the Global.asax File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#GlobalAsax)

Comment: That's not the job for ServletContextListener. This interface handles two events: application startup and application shutdown (put it ik other terms).

Comment: Really? "void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
Receives notification that the ServletContext is about to be shut down."

Comment: The ServletContext is the application scope. It means that the application is being stopped or undeployed. This interface doesn't notify if the servlets are ready or not to use, they may be loaded but that's not relevant for the task at hand. Also, it allows you to access to the Application scope in case you want to store data before the users start interacting with the web app.

Comment: By the way, you mention applicatoon events and that seems similar (at least from what I can read). Could you give me more light about it?

Comment: That file contains what I need and more. That's the asp.net equivalent for this abd other listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend more on the server than anything that is standard in .net.  If you are hosting on Katana with Owin then you would do something with the appbuilder in startup but if you are deploying to IIS then global.asax has functions to tie into like application_startup.

Useful links:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/

http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/owin-katana-and-getting-started